# Camel AggregationStrategy and batch size property?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using an implementation of the `AggregationStrategy` API to aggregate message from a batch consumer (FTP) and I was expecting to be able to retrieve the "CamelBatchSize" and "CamelBatchIndex" property values from the exchange headers in the `aggregate` method, but these header properties return `null`. If I log these properties just before the aggregation they  return the expected values. Does anyone know if the aggregation process removes them?

Comment: Its not a header, its set as exchange property. And no the aggregator does not remove anything.

Comment: Oh, `${header.CamelBatchSize}` in the route returns a value but `exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelBatchSize")` in my Processor doesn't, so does that mean the simple language expression is searching exchange properties and exchanges headers?

Comment: Yeah it does as it was implemented like that in the beginning as a convenience and now we are keeping that behavior to be backwards compatible